# Renaming folder and Moving folder in FTP via iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp

I am trying to rename a folder in FTP via ios.
I have implemented Black Raccoon library for FTP. Like all other libraries I've com across, it has options for creating, deleting and uploading files to a specific ftp. However renaming  a folder or moving a folder are absent.
I've read the CFNetworking doc provided in Apple developer site. here also they have completely avoided the question of renaming a folder or moving a folder.
The question is how can I approach this problem? Should I try to use FTP commands? If so, how should I use these commands in objective C?

Comment: How you solved this problem ? Did you succeeded with folder rename ?

Answer (score 0):

Black Raccoon doesn't do anything more than what Apple provides - and you are correct they DO avoid renaming or moving folders. There are other libraries that do provide a more comprehensive FTP protocol, however they are not for the faint of heart.

Black Raccoon was designed purely for systems which have already been set up - not as an ftp management tool. It is a "light" ftp library as opposed to a full-fledged "heavy" ftp library.

Comment: Then, what library should I use to implement these functionalities?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer that. I needed a light, modern FTP library and I forked White Raccoon to Black Raccoon (and substantially rewrote good chunks of it). What would be required to rename or move a folder would require in-depth understanding of the RFC documents on FTP.